# When will experiment be deleted with lifecycle_stage is set as deleted

Tags: mlflow

I can see experiment 2 is in deleted, but when it will be deleted actually?

```
2   test    hdfs:///1234/mlflow deleted
```

If the experiment is not deleted automatically, how can I delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you use sql store?

Currently there is no way to tell mlflow to hard-delete experiments. We are working with open source contributors to add a cli command that would perform garbage-collection of deleted experiments. This should be added soon in one of the upcoming mlflow releases. In the meantime, you can connect to your sql store and delete the experiments manually.